# Recurrence Relations using generating functions

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

How do we solve:

\begin{align}
a_n &= 4a_{n-1} + 4a_{n-2}, \ \ \text{ for } n\ge 2\\
a_0 &= 6,\\
a_1 &= 8.
\end{align}

I know we can solve it using characteristic equations i.e. considering $r^2 -4r + 4 = 0$ and then calculating the coefficients and all.

But is there a way to do it using generating functions?

Comment: Just look at any source that introduces generating functions, such recurrences are usually one of the first examples (e.g. Fibonacci sequence).

Comment: take your recurrence relation, multiply it with x^n and sum over the admitted values of n

Comment: given that f(x)=sum a_n x^n you can find the other terms